# how to perform calculations for each record in collection

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, eloquent, collections

i have an collection of bets, where i need to calculate var $profit.
Each record has stake and odds.

Here is my collection:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1900 ▼
  #items: array:4 [▼
    0 => App\Models\Bet {#1912 ▶}
    1 => App\Models\Bet {#1906 ▶}
    2 => App\Models\Bet {#1857 ▶}
    3 => App\Models\Bet {#1882 ▶}
  ]
}
```

and attributes of array:

```
#attributes: array:19 [▼
        "id" => 4
        "user_id" => 1
        "status_id" => 1
        "content" => "some text"
        "sport" => "Basketball"
        "competition" => "Premier league"
        "start_date" => "2021-12-08"
        "bookmaker_id" => 1
        "team1" => "team one"
        "team2" => "team two"
        "selection_id" => 1
        "tip" => "2,5"
        "odds" => "5"
        "unit_id" => 5
        "created_at" => "2021-12-06 13:32:46"
        "updated_at" => "2021-12-06 13:32:46"
        "created_by" => 1
        "updated_by" => null
        "deleted_by" => null
      ]
```

how can i make calculations in each collection array?
for exmpl to count profit (odds*unit_id(stake))

Comment: use the collection `map` method. or you can use [accessors](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators)

Comment: You can wil [local scope](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#local-scopes)

Answer (score 0):

this was the thing i needed:

```
$bets = array_map(function($item) {
     $item['won'] = number_format((double)$item['odds'] * (int)$item['unit_id'],3);
            return $item;
        }, $bets);
```